# Hough transform accumulator setting (rho)

Tags: opencv, hough-transform, card.io

I have been studying the algorithms of card.io and I have some difficulties when reading the Hough transform script.

For Hough transform, it is required to setup the accumulator, a grid that stores the vote in (rho, theta) space.

In `card.io-dmz/cv/hough.cpp` (https://github.com/card-io/card.io-dmz/blob/master/cv/hough.cpp#L99) line 99, It saids the number of rho `numrho` is given by

```
numrho = cvRound(((width + height) * 2 + 1) / rho);
```

Here `width` and `height` are the dimension of the ROI and `rho` is the distance resolution.

**Question:** I do not understand why the numerator is `(width + height) * 2 + 1`.

My guess is that `+ 1` is to count the zero value, and `* 2` is to count both +ve rho and -ve rho.

But I still don't understand why `width + height` appears. I think it is more intuitive to replace it by `sqrt(width*width + height*height)`, which is the largest possible value in rho.

This setting is also used in OpenCV (see this link: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/hough.cpp#L128)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Excellent question. If I had to guess *why*, a possible answer is because at any angle, it is possible to hit every single edge pixel (every pixel in `height` and every pixel in `width`)  with varying values of `rho`. However these wouldn't be equally spaced `rho` values to hit those, so I agree that it doesn't make any sense; the maximum "resolution" you could get is just along the diagonal. I'd open up an issue on OpenCV's GitHub and see what others have to say.